# How do I return json for 404s and 403s in WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a fairly simple web API application that currently has one route setup.  If the user attempts to access any other route they get a 404 back but the body of the 404 is HTML instead of JSON (which is what their accept header asks for).  What is the *easiest* (least code/config added to my project) way to get IIS to respond to requests of non-existant routes with a JSON error response rather than a webpage?

The same question applies to 403s.  If I try to navigate to the root of my application I get a 403 back, once again as a webpage.  I would prefer this be a 404, but the bigger question is how do I make *all* responses from my application be JSON rather than only responses on valid routes?  I mention the 403 because I am looking for a broader solution than just setting up a catch-all route, since I don't believe that will help me with the 403 or any other random exception that occurs outside of a controller action.

Preferrably, I would like my application to respect the accept header on the request.  However, since my API only supports JSON right now, I am willing to live with (for the time being) it always responding with JSON.

I'm using WebAPI 2.2 and .NET 4.5.2.

**Edit**

This isn't a formatter issue.  The formatters are correctly applied to successful messages, respecting the accept header in the request.  This is specifically an issue with unhandled routes and web server errors (like forbidden when trying to access web root).

**Edit 2**

*Steps to reproduce:*

1. Open Visual Studio 2013 Update 4
2. New Project
3. Choose .NET Framework 4.5.2
4. Choose Templates > Visual C# > Web > ASP.NET Web Application
5. Choose "Empty", leave all folders and core references **unchecked**.
6. Right Click on the project > Add > New Scaffold Item > Web API 2 Controller - Empty
7. Modify DefaultController as shown below.
8. Modify WebApiConfig.cs as shown below.
9. Run/Debug

What I expect is that when I navigate to `http://localhost:<port>/api/do_stuff` I see `Success!` in either XML or JSON depending on accept headers (which I do) and when I navigate to any other page I should see `Failure!` (which I don't).  Instead when I navigate to any other page I see IIS's 404 response.

DefaultController.cs:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class DefaultController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("do_stuff")]
    public String DoStuff()
    {
        return "Success!";
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Filters.Add(new CustomExceptionFilter());
    }

    private class CustomExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            if (actionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                actionExecutedContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(@"""Failure!"""),
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 3**

I have also tried adding a global exception handler and exception logger as shown here:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling

Neither are called when I try to navigate to an invalid route or navigate to site root in the above example.

Comment: If the accept header is text/html and not application/json then returning HTML might be the correct thing to do anyhow.

Comment: I don't believe that answer applies here because the accept header is currently set to application/json yet I am getting back text/html.  This implies that my formatters aren't being respected for missing routes and forbidden requests.

Comment: Though I will check the steps mentioned by you and revert, but can you make CustomExceptionFilter a standalone public class, what's the point of making it a private class, my understanding is even when you have registered, it will only be working for exception inside WebAPIConfig and that's why it is not firing on any of the exception encountered

Comment: Making the exception filter a non-nested public class did not change the behavior.  I made it private for design/style reasons, it doesn't need to be instantiated or accessed outside of WebApiConfig so all making it public would do is pollute the namespace.  It implements IExceptionFilter, which is public, and that is what gets passed around.

Comment: Thanks for the verification, this seems to be the case where Web API code does not seems to be even called, Error seems to be returning from the web server itself as it cannot get a valid resource or there's no permission to access the site root. My understanding is any custom code exception will be caught and if it does, then we have veered away from the main question. In that case exception filters cannot handle such cases, as it would require exception to be thrown in  the Web API execution

Comment: With 404 there's probably no route match, which means the application won't hit the MVC related architecture, thus ExceptionFilter will not work and a default response will be returned. The solution is to use a middleware to handle 404 errors, where i'd pay attention on the requested Accept-type, as: if its application/json, it's sure the client is requesting a JSON response. Another way to determine the type would be to check if the route started with /api /odata prefixes...

Answer (score 1):

To configure IIS to respond with a JSON error response for non-existent routes and other server errors, you can use the CustomErrors feature in your web.config file. Here's what you can do:

Open your project in Visual Studio.
Locate the web.config file in the root directory of your project.
Add or modify the <system.web> and <system.webServer> sections as follows:

```
 <system.web>
   <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/error" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error/notfound" />
   <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/error/forbidden" />
 </customErrors>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="~/error/notfound" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  <error statusCode="403" path="~/error/forbidden" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
 </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Create a new folder named "Error" in the root directory of your project.
Inside the "Error" folder, create two new files: "NotFound.cshtml" and "Forbidden.cshtml" (or .cshtml.cs if you're using Razor Pages) with the following content:
NotFound.cshtml:

```
@{
   Response.StatusCode = 404;
   Layout = null;
}

{"error": "Not found"}
```

Forbidden.cshtml:

```
@{
   Response.StatusCode = 403;
   Layout = null;
}

{"error": "Forbidden"}
```

These files will return a JSON error response with the appropriate status code.

Now, when a user attempts to access a non-existent route, they will receive a JSON error response instead of the default 404 HTML page. Similarly, when accessing the root of your application, a 403 response will be returned as JSON.

Make sure to adjust the error messages and formatting according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Call the function below from your planned catch-all-route to return a jsonResult Action like below

```
public JsonResult Handle404()
{
   return Json(new { error404 = "NOT FOUND", Message = "Additional Message" });
}
```

which will produce

```
var result =
{
  "error404": "NOT FOUND",
  "Message": "Additional Message"
}; 

alert(result.error404);
allert(result.Message);
```

Comment: A catch-all route will solve the 404s explicitly, but what about all of the other exceptions that my application might throw?  An easy to reproduce example is the 403 I get when I try to access the root of my application.  Others might include IIS configuration errors, application configuration errors, application crashes, etc.  I understand that I probably can't get IIS to return JSON for truly fatal errors (like out of memory) but I would like JSON responses for everything possible.

Answer (score -1):

Call httpget for response 404 notfound use this

```
public JsonResult DoSomething() {
        try
        {

            var result = getData();
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(HttpNotFound());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is this for .NET 4.5.2 or .NET Core?

Comment: it for over .NET 4.6.1